# Extract a property from array into a union type

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects:

```
export const myArr = [
  { id: 'type 1', ... },
  { id: 'type 2', ... },
  { id: 'type 3', ... },
  ...
] as const;
```

I want to extract the `id` property into a union type.
The desired result is:

```
export type MyTypes = 'type 1' | 'type 2' | 'type 3' | ...;
```

I've tried:

```
export type MyTypes = Extract<(typeof myArr)[number], 'id'>;
```

but the compiler insists on yielding this as `type MyTypes = never`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) rather than `Extract`, or just `typeof myArr[number]["id"]` - https://tsplay.dev/W4bdeN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(**jonrsharpe** was first to post a comment before I finished my answer, but let me still post it to explain it in more details)*

First of all, the `Extract` utility type is for doing something different - when you have e.g. types `A` and `B`:

```
type A = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type B = 'b' | 'c' | 'd';
```

then the type returned by `Extract<A, B>` extracts all members of union type `A` which can be assigned to type `B`.

Another maybe more useful example - for type:

`type C = 'a' | 'b' | 1 | 10;`

The type `Extract<C, string>` is `'a' | 'b'`

See the documentation for more details:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union

E.g. see:

[image]

Now, to get what you want you need to use:

````
type Id = (typeof myArr)[number]['id'];
``

Or, using the `Pick` suggested in the comment you'd have to use:

```ts
type Id = Pick<(typeof myArr)[number], 'id'>['id'];
````

Note that it is more complex than the example in the comment to your question, because `Pick<(typeof myArr)[number], 'id'>` would give you type:

```
type Id = {
    readonly id: "type 1" | "type 2" | "type 3";
}
```

which is an object type with key `id` that haas the type `"type 1" | "type 2" | "type 3"`, not just the type `"type 1" | "type 2" | "type 3"` that you need.

See how it looks in VSCode:

[image]

[image]